# How to evaluate an Haskell expression immediately?

Tags: haskell, evaluation, strict

When I use JS, I have two options to handle a function.

```
var a = function() {};
var b = a;     // b is the function a itself.
var c = a();   // c is result of the evaluation of function a.
```

AFAIK, Haskell is lazy by default, so I always get `b` by default. But if I want to get `c`, how can I do?

### Update

I think I should put a word *explicitly*.

I was doing something like this in `ghci`.

```
let a = getLine
a
```

I wanted to let a result of `getLine` into `a`.

### Update2

I note this code for later reference for people like me.
I could correct translation to Haskell with @Ankur's help.
With above code example is not a good one because function `a` doesn't return anything.
If I change it like this;

```
var a = function(x,y) { return x * y; };
var b = a;     // b is the function a itself.
var c = a();   // c is result of the evaluation of function a.
```

Translation into Haskell will become like this.

```
let a = \ x y -> x* y    // Anonymous lambda function.
let b = a
let c = a 100 200
```

Comment: You probably want a string, but `getline` has the type `IO String`. IO is a special kind of box, you can put stuff inside but cannot get it back, ever. You need to read up on Haskell monadic I/O system.

Comment: @n.m. `you can put stuff inside but cannot get it back, ever` that is not correct. It should be: you have to work inside the context of the box to play with the value inside the box.

Comment: @Ankur You csn put it like that, yes. Bit I was not going to give a monad tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for discussion, but anyway, basic examples like that are more valuable and helpful to beginners like me. I just hope I would understand what the Monad is eventually.

Comment: Note that since in Haskell all functions are in [curried form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), the JavaScript function `function(x,y) { return x*y; }` translates to `\(x,y) -> x * y`. The Haskell function `\x y -> x * y` would be `function(x) { return function(y) { return x*y; } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code would translate to Haskell as:

```
Prelude> let a = (\() -> ())
Prelude> let b = a
Prelude> let c = a()
```

Your JS function was taking Nothing (which you can model as () type) and returning nothing i.e again ()

`getLine` is a value of type `IO String` so if you say `let a = getLine`, `a` becomes value of type `IO String`. What you want is extract `String` from this `IO String`, which can be done as:

`a <- getLine`

Comment: I never know Haskell functions also can be called with `()` operator.

Comment: @Eonil: `()` is a type in Haskell which has just one value, which is also called `()`. Since it's a value, you can pass it around to functions which accept values of the `()` type. If you then remove some space between the function name and the argument, you get that strange look, e.g. `id()` is `id ()` which is `()`.

Comment: Don't get confused, `()` is not an operator, but a type (when in a type signature) and a value in the above use.  So `a ()` is the function `a` applied to the value `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the parallel to Javascript isn't quite correct -- for instance, assuming `a` returns a number, `b + b` makes sense in Haskell but not in your example Javascript. In principle functions in Haskell are functions of exactly one argument -- what appears to be a function of two arguments is a function of one argument, which returns a function of one argument, which returns a value. `b` in Haskell would not be an unevaluated "zero-argument function", but an unevaluated value.

To introduce strictness you can use `seq`, which takes two arguments, the first of which is strictly evaluated and the second of which is returned. [Read more](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Seq).

Here is an example from that page where `seq` is used to force immediate evaluation of `z'`:

```
foldl' :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl' _ z [] = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `seq` foldl' f z' xs
```

Note the way `z'` is used again later as the second argument to `foldl'`, since `seq` just discards the value of its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. Haskell is [non-strict](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_vs._non-strict), not lazy.
2. Many expressions will be evaluated strictly, see [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness), so you can often force strictness simply with the structure of your code.
3. In Haskell, if `c` has a type which matches the return type - the value - of `a()` then that is what will be assigned to it (never the function itself).
4. Haskell may put off the calculation until your code actually needs the value of `c` but in most cases you should not care.

Why do you want to force the evaluation early?  Usually, the only reason to do this in Haskell is performance.  In less pure languages, you might be depending on a side effect but that will not be the case in Haskell - unless you're working with, say, the IO monad and that gives you all you need to force sequential evaluation.

**UPDATE** Ah, so you *are* working with [IO](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside).